# Firebase Cloud Function Does Not Send Response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

here is my code of http cloud function that reads some documents and then send response

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    var orderId;
    var result = "";

    var userId;
    var promoCode;
    var promoRef;
    var userDocRef;

    var promoCodeDoc;

    //userId = req.body.userId;
    //orderId = req.body.orderId;
    promoCode = req.body.promoCode;

    //userDocRef = db.collection("Users").doc()
    promoRef = db.collection("PromoCodes").doc(promoCode);


    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
      return t.get(promoRef)
        .then(promoCodeDoc => {
            if(promoCodeDoc.exists){
              result = "OK";
              res.json(result);
            }else{
              result = "Invalid Promocode!";
              res.json(result);

            }
          //t.update(cityRef, {population: newPopulation});
          return true;
        });
    }).then(result => {
      console.log('Transaction success!');
      return true;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    });

    return Promise.all(transaction());
```

But This is not sending the response because functions ends but Firestore Transaction is still runnning in background . 
Any Solution to my problem ?

Comment: Two things.  First, this doesn't look like a complete function.  Could you edit it to show the entire minimal code that has a problem?  There has to be code missing.  Second, sending a response *inside* the transaction handler seems like a really bad idea.  Why wouldn't you do that after the transaction fully completes?

Comment: @DougStevenson sending a response inside the transaction handler is intended usage for the firebase SDK, and [is shown in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). i.e. the `runTransaction()` block, to my eyes, doesn't seem to contain any issues. It's actually pretty similar to one of the firebase doc examples.

Comment: @John That documentation doesn't say anything about how Cloud Functions works with respect to Firestore transactions.  The real problem here is that a transaction handler may be run multiple times in order to deal with contention at the location of the transaction.  If the handler is sending a response, it may en up doing so multiple times, which will cause the function to crash, because the Response object only allows one response to be sent...

Comment: @John and in a more general sense, transaction handlers are not supposed to change application state, and sending a response is definitely changing the state of the response.  So it's a bad idea.

Comment: i am sending response outside the transaction i did this because my code was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` expects a single array of promises as its argument, but you're not giving it an array argument. Secondly, the `transaction` variable is a promise, not a function. You can't call `()` a promise.

So I think the correct code would be `return Promise.all([transaction])`. This being said, you only have one promise so you don't need `Promise.all` and can just `return transaction`.

Not sure if this will solve all your problems though. If you log into the firebase console, navigate to the functions section, there's a "Logs" tab that allows you to see debugging output from your function executions. It might help you track down all the problems. I imagine there are already console errors logged pointing out the fact that `transaction()` is not a function.